# Switching context on Selenium via node's wd module

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I can only find documentation for java clients. I managed to find the implementation for it on node's `wd` client but i can't figure out where exactly it resides on the module's external API. Not even sure what the `commands` module from that source file points to:

https://github.com/admc/wd/pull/267

where am i supposed to add it on a simple test like:

```
var chai = require("chai");
var chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
chai.should();
var wd = require('wd');
var wd_options = {
   hostname: '127.0.0.1',
   port: 4444
}
// TODO change context to webview?
browser.init({"platformName":...})
  .get("http://example.com/")
  .title()
  .should.become('fail test')
  .done(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the docs at https://github.com/admc/wd/blob/master/doc/api.md but nothing on https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol

this seems to be the right place to use it:

```
browser.init({"platformName":...})
  .context("WEBVIEW_1")
  .get("http://example.com/")
  ...
```